# RESTful url of classes with collections?

Tags: web-services, rest, web-applications

I'm implementing a webapp and would like to comply with RESTfull design standarts, my question is.

Given a class with a collection.

Person {
    id   :: integer
    name :: string
    friends :: collection of Persons
}

What would be the 'most' correct way to implement the Person-class's interface:

1.

```
example.com/REST/persons -> [... {id: '2', name: 'Pete', friends: [1,4,6]} ... ]
example.com/REST/persons/2 -> {id: '2', name: 'Pete', friends: [1,4,6]}
```

Where the friends are to be looked up by using some search function on the persons class?

**or**

2.

```
example.com/REST/persons -> [... {id: '2', name: 'Pete'} ... ]
example.com/REST/persons/2 -> {id: '2', name: 'Pete'}
example.com/REST/persons/2/friends -> [{id: '1', name: 'Joann'}, 
                                       {id: '4', name: 'Jim'},
                                       {id: '6', name: 'Charlie'}]
```

Where the elements in the collection are looked up as a field in the person instance.

I've seen both things implemented, but I would like to comply with the standarts.

a thirth way was just surgested to me.

```
example.com/REST/persons/2 -> {id     : '2', 
                               name   : 'Pete', 
                               friends: [example.com/REST/person/1,
                                         example.com/REST/person/4,
                                         example.com/REST/person/6]}
```

hence making the interface event more RESTfull -- the client can now traverse the entire interface without knowing anything about the implementation.

I hope there is some input somewhere out there.

Comment: What technology are you planning to use to implement you REST API? That choice could make this decision for you.

Comment: Also your question title is misleading, it looks like you are looking for URL format rather than actual implementation.

Comment: @Zepplock: I changed the title

Comment: @RaySaltrelli: Shouldn't the interface be implementation independant, I would think thats the whole point of having a RESTfull interface..

Comment: In theory, yes.  But theory often doesn't translate into practice without a few compromises.  For example, if you choose ASP.NET Web API for your REST API then implementing option 2 will be rather difficult because it will require mixing purist-style REST with RPC-style REST and Web API doesn't like that.

Comment: @RaySaltrelli: I'm implementing in top of the erlang cowboy web server, and would at least like to think that serverside compatibility is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Having `example.com/REST/persons/{person-id}/friends/{friends-id}` is a right approach. REST itself does not enforce any URL composition rules but that is what most people do.

Basically you have a resource `Person` and a subresource `Friend` with many to many relationship.

Comment: what about friends, friends then? Doesn't thing make for a very unclean and long interface?

Comment: Well the idea is that with this URL you can easily see the relationship. For each ```Person``` you can get a list of friends. There's no need to chain those resources more than 2 levels deep.

Comment: Someone else just told me that the correct way could be to serve a list of url's in the top object... hence making the access to the resourse even more RESTfull

Comment: That is in fact a more RESTful way but it's less practical in my opinion. It'll result in many new requests. Use it only if you can reliably cache those for performance reasons.